# How to add language prefix in Symfony routes.php

Tags: php, symfony, locale

I'm trying to implement language prefixes in an existing Symfony 5.3.9 project.
So far I've created `/config/routes/annotations.yaml` with:

```
controllers:
  resource: ../../src/Controller/
  type: annotation
  prefix: /{_locale}
  requirements:
      _locale: en|fr|ar|nl
  defaults:
    _locales: 'en'
```

And `/config/routes/routes.yaml` with

```
legacy:
  resource: .
  type:     legacy

api_login:
    path: /api/login
    methods: ['POST']

api_logout:
    path: /api/logout

contact:
    path:       /{_locale}/contact
    controller: App\Controller\ContactController::index
    requirements:
        _locale: en|fr|ar|nl

app_index:
  path: /en

redirect:
   path: /
   controller: App\Controller\RedirectController::redirectToLocale
```

`App\Controller\RedirectController::redirectToLocale`:

```
public function redirectToLocale(): Response
{
    return $this->redirectToRoute('app_index');
}
```

Path `http://localhost:8000/activities/nearme`: responds with `LegacyController`

This works on most of the pages, but throws an error "No route found for "GET http://localhost:8000/en/activities/nearme" (from "http://localhost:8000/en/")" if I try to access some of the pages. I've found that routes for them are defined in /routes.php. So, I  add locale prefixes there like that:

```
$this->addRoute('activities', '{_locale}/activities', 'ActivitiesController', 'activities');
```

Command

```
$ php74 bin/console debug:router activities
```

shows me:

```
+--------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
| Property     | Value                                                   |
+--------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
| Route Name   | activities                                              |
| Path         | /{_locale}/activities                                   |
| Path Regex   | {^/(?P<_locale>en|fr|ar|nl)/activities$}sD              |
| Host         | ANY                                                     |
| Host Regex   |                                                         |
| Scheme       | ANY                                                     |
| Method       | GET|POST                                                |
| Requirements | _locale: en|fr|ar|nl                                    |
| Class        | Symfony\Component\Routing\Route                         |
| Defaults     | _controller: rox.legacy_controller::showLegacyPage()    |
| Options      | compiler_class: Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCompiler |
```

But when I try to access http://localhost:8000/en/activities it throws:

```
Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\ResourceNotFoundException:
No routes found for "en".
```

If I hardcode locale like that:

```
$this->addRoute('activities', 'en/activities', 'ActivitiesController', 'activities');
```

It redirects me to http://localhost:8000/en/activities/nearme and throws

```
No route found for "GET http://localhost:8000/en/activities/nearme"
```

If I add prefix to /activities/nearme:

```
$this->addRoute('activities_near_me', 'en/activities/nearme', 'ActivitiesController', 'activitiesNearMe');
```

and try to access http://localhost:8000/en/activities it redirects to http://localhost:8000/en/en/activities/nearme (doubles the prefix)
and throws

```
No route found for "GET http://localhost:8000/en/en/activities/nearme"
```

If I manually enter http://localhost:8000/en/activities/nearme it opens the page successfully.

Comment: I think the problem is that in `/config/routes/annotations.yaml` `defaults:` `_locales:` should be `_locale:`?

Comment: Additionally [`default_locale: en`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#default-locale) can be defined on the `framework` config, which will add the locale to the request if it has not been specified. Aside from that what is inside `App\Controller\RedirectController::redirectToLocale`?

Comment: @WillB. `redirectToLocale`:  
    `public function redirectToLocale(): Response  
      {  
        return $this->redirectToRoute('app_index');  
      }  `
And `app_index` is:  
   ` app_index:  
      path: /en`

Comment: @user16822867 didn't help. Have updated the question.

Comment: @r69 what is the code of `ActivitiesController`?